# Assign to object passed as argument in ES5

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I have an object that I pass as an argument into a function. Inside that function I want to assign to it a different value, but because inside the function we have only reference to the original object we can not use simple assignment with =.

In ES2015 I could use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Is there a workaround I could use in ES5, other than copying properties to the reference?

Here is an example https://jsbin.com/wimuvaqosi/1/edit?js,console

```
var x = {prop:1};

function foo(x1) {
  var y = {prop:2};
  x1 = y; //this obviously does not work
  //x1 = Object.assign(x1, y); //this works only in ES2015
}

foo(x);

console.log("x ", x);
```

Comment: In your example: x1.prop=2; you can modify every object to be equal to another. No need to recreate one

Comment: `Object.assign` does not assign `x` to a different object. It copies all properties of `y` to `x`. @baao's answer mimics 'Object.assign' exactly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a workaround I could use in ES5, other than copying properties to the reference?

Not really, Object.assign also just copies properties. But you can simply use the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill)  and use Object.assign() in your pre es2015 code:

```
if (typeof Object.assign != 'function') {
  Object.assign = function(target) {
    'use strict';
    if (target == null) {
      throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
    }

    target = Object(target);
    for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
      var source = arguments[index];
      if (source != null) {
        for (var key in source) {
          if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) {
            target[key] = source[key];
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return target;
  };
}
```

Comment: It's not that only the polyfill copies properties, that's just what `Object.assign` does.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to change `x` to a different object completely. If so you cannot, thankfully, do it. Even `Object.assign(x, y)` just copies properties from `x` to `y` just like @baao's polfill. `x` still references the same object. But you can:

```
var x = {prop:1};
function foo(x1) {
    var y = {prop:2};
    return y;
}
x = foo(x);
console.log("x ", x);
```

Or

```
var x = {prop:1};
function foo(ref) {
    var y = {prop:2};
    ref.x = y;
}
var refX = {x: x};
foo(refX);
console.log("x ", refX.x);
```

IMO these solutions are better than what you are looking for because the caller can see that variable `x` now points to a different object - and this might matter. For example in the Javascript language the caller may always make assumption such as:

```
 y = x;
 foo(x);
 y === x; // always true
```

I could have references to `x` from lookup tables and other structures, and these would not get replaced - it could get very confusing. In other languages, like C# you can pass object by reference, but there is a different call signature like `foo(ref x);` so you can easily see that x may be replaced when you read the code.

Comment: I am sorry, what you propose are workarounds, not solutions

Comment: There is no solution so a a workaround is a helpful answer.

Comment: why thankfully? I find the passing of reference instead of passing the object itself very confusing

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek I have edited by answer to explain.